# How to grant select on information_schema.views in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, view, sql-grant, information-schema

Is there any way to grant read-access on the information_schema-objects, in this case the views-table?

I want to run my web application with a very restricted user, but at some places he needs to query information_schema.views for debugging purposes. I guess only users with superusers rights will be allowed to do this, or is there any other way? Don't like to run my web app with maximum user grants...

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to `GRANT` rights. All users can read from views in the [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-schema.html) by default.

Comment: You're right. First i thought the information_schema would only list owners objects, but it'll show up all items granted to the user selecting from information_schema. Thanks